# How to dump full llvm build log?

Tags: cmake, build

When I build llvm with cmake, I get the following log of clang-tidy build.

---

Scanning dependencies of target clang-tidy
Building CXX object tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-tidy/tool/CMakeFiles/clang-tidy.dir/ClangTidyToolMain.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../../../../../bin/clang-tidy

---

And I want to know the build command like "g++ ClangTidyToolMain.cpp ...". So where can I find out the build details?

I want to know the link library when to build with "g++ ClangTidyToolMain.cpp.o -o clang-tidy -lxxx"

Answer (score 0):

I find it in `"build/tools/clang/tools/extra/clang-tidy/tool/CMakeFiles/clang-tidy.dir/link.txt"`

And the option works.

```
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE
```